# Creating a data object relationship system

Tags: database, graph, relationship, cmdb

I would like to store an object that has a name and some attribute and any kind of database and have another that that document relationship between between them

Let say this

Object A
Object B
Object C
Object D

A is related to B
A is related to D
B is related to C

All relation have also attribute that give the relation order (uni (from,to) or (to,from) or bidrectional).

Then, I would like to do some query that will show me A is related to C by passing in B.  A kind of path between 2 objects.

Kind of graph database like Neo4J

Thanks for  your input

Answer (score 1):

Question is rather old but anyways:

The Neo4j documentation actually has an example that is very close to answering the question.
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graph-algo-path-finding.html